# Android: Can Canvas write text ontop of an image?

Tags: android

I have a custom button image and I need the text to appear in the very top of it to allow the picture below it to not be covered. I don't think this is possible with normal buttons and background images.

Is it possible to use Canvas to write onto an already created image and use that as a button?

The only other way I can see of doing this is by using vector images, but android cannot use this am I right?

If there are any better ways that would be good to know too thanks.

EDIT:
9 patch is a solution, but it still means that the text is a fixed size. Plus the image has a lot happening on it with shadows and drawings. It is not actually the best way I think. I know I can create separately sized images for different size screens. I am just looking for something that means the text does not have to be completely fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the text on a image. Just override the

```
  @ Override
public void onDraw ( Canvas canvas ) {

    try {
        canvas.drawColor ( Color.BLACK ) ;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource ( getResources ( ) , ( R.drawable.background_image ) ) ;

        canvas.drawBitmap ( bitmap , 0 , 0 , null ) ;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText("Text to be drwaw", my_txt_x_position, my_txt_y_position, paint);

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace ( ) ;
    } catch ( Error e ) {
        e.printStackTrace ( ) ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know something about nine-patch images?
[nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Comment: That's a good point! The only problem then is I will have to create different images for different screen sizes. If there is no other way then I shall accept this answer. Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of that

Comment: Sorry I tried and realised why it is not the best solution. The images I have are using shadows and drawings that means hardly any can be resized without the whole image distorting. Thanks again though for your help.